# UITextField text is not being saved

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I have some `UITextField` property :

```
 @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *phone;
```

and in the .h file i have set the delegate with :

```
<UITextFieldDelegate>
```

and synthesise it.

Than to create a text field i send that `phone` to a function :

```
  [self createTextFieldWithText:self.phone AndRect:CGRectMake(25, 100, 250, 60) AndText:@"Phone Number"];
```

that is:

```
-(void)createTextFieldWithText:(UITextField*)text AndRect:(CGRect)rect AndText:(NSString*)inText
{
    text = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    text.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    text.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:26];
    text.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    text.placeholder = inText;
    text.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Apple SD Gothic Neo" size:26];
    text.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    text.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    text.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    text.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
    text.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
    [text setDelegate:self];
    [self.view addSubview:text];
}
```

and have a delegate method:

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)mytextField
{
    NSLog(@"did begin");
    mytextField.text=@"";

    //change nack send button color
    [self.phoneB setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0/255. green:0/255. blue:0/255. alpha:1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```

what happens is that the text in that field is not being saved after i am trying to use it. for example if i later do :

```
  phone.text
```

I see nothing inside.

Comment: Now i can see that its being called but its not removing the inner text as i request from it with .text=@"";

Comment: After you have added the textfield can you NSLog it's delegate to see if it's been set correctly?

Comment: NSLog your self.phone textfield object and the mytextField object inside the delegate call to ensure they are the same object.

Comment: they are not… because i am sending a pointer to the function. question is, how can i create on function and send it the real label adress

Comment: phone is point on null...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is rather strange method call.
You should do this instead:

```
self.phone = [self createTextFieldWithRect:CGRectMake(25, 100, 250, 60) AndText:@"Phone Number"];
```

And the method returns the initiated text field as output.

```
-(UITextField *)createTextFieldWithRect:(CGRect)rect AndText:(NSString*)inText
{
    UITextField *text = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    text.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    text.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:26];
    text.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    text.placeholder = inText;
    text.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Apple SD Gothic Neo" size:26];
    text.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    text.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    text.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    text.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
    text.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
    [text setDelegate:self];
    [self.view addSubview:text];

    return text;
}
```

The thing is, in the current implementation, you are sending the null object into the function.
The compiler would not have the reference to the self.phone object yet. (It has not been created.)

Comment: As a thought experiment, would his original implementation have worked if he has passed in the ivar reference i.e. '_phone'